# Angular Material : How to add multiple chips when comma separated string is added in the input?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm using this syntax to create chips -

```
<md-chips ng-model="someModel" md-separator-keys="seperatorKeys">
                            <md-chip-template >
                                <span>{{$chip}}</span>
                            </md-chip-template>
                        </md-chips>
```

and this is part of the controller code.

```
$scope.seperatorKeys = [$mdConstant.KEY_CODE.ENTER, $mdConstant.KEY_CODE.COMMA];
```

Now I want to create multiple chips if I **paste** comma seperated string in the input to add chips, let's say, 
For e.g. if I enter `1234,5678` as an input, it should create `1234` as first chip and `5678` as second chip.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: Is [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWmBqL) what you mean?

Comment: @troig no. If I PASTE `1234,5678` in the textbox, it should create two chips - `1234` and `5678`

Comment: Something that has been requested in this issue - https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3399

Comment: OK @Vishwajeet Vatharkar, Now I know what you mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the solution is very simple - something like following ---

In the controller, write a method to be used on `md-transform-chip`, and manipulate the array containing chips in the scope, using the method.

Then, `return null` so that no new chip will be created.

```
 $scope.addMultipleChips = function (chip, model) {
        var seperatedString = angular.copy(chip);
        seperatedString = seperatedString.toString();
        var chipsArray = seperatedString.split();
        angular.forEach(chipsArray, function (chipToAdd) {
            $scope[model].push(chipToAdd);
        });
        return null;
    };
```

And declare it in the template like this -

```
<md-chips ng-model="someModel" md-separator-keys="seperatorKeys"
md-transform-chip="addMultipleChips($chip, 'someModel')">
                                <md-chip-template >
                                    <span>{{$chip}}</span>
                                </md-chip-template>
                            </md-chips>
```

Here's a JSFiddle for the same.
http://jsfiddle.net/vishwajeetv/2f6qscrp/255/

Comment: I don't seem to get the solution. I pasted string `1234,5678` in the fiddle which you have provided,but chips were not created

Comment: @Nishant123 try pasting this -  1234,5678 and press enter key

Comment: You may need to check that the model isn't `undefined` before calling `model.push()`. If it's undefined, you'll need to set it to an empty array first. If all the chips are deleted and the md-chips has `required`, the model value will be `undefined` and your code would throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a clean solution which is working according to your requirement.

for Eg. when  if you enter 1234,5678 as an input, it should create 1234 as first chip and 5678 as second chip `on-enter` as well as on typing `comma`.

Add attribute `md-transform-chip` in html and change your controller like

HTML

```
<md-chips ng-model="values" placeholder="Comma separated values" 
          md-separator-keys="seperatorKeys" md-transform-chip="addChips($chip)">
    <md-chip-template>
        <span>{{$chip}}</span>
    </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('home').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $mdConstant) {
  $scope.seperatorKeys = [$mdConstant.KEY_CODE.ENTER, $mdConstant.KEY_CODE.COMMA];
  $scope.values = [];

  $scope.addChips = function(chips) {
    var chipsArray = chips.split(',');
    angular.forEach(chipsArray, function(chip) {
      if ($scope.values.indexOf(chip) < 0) { 
        $scope.values.push(chip);
      }
    });
    return null;
  };
});
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbLv7aj8/50/)

Comment: I like your approach but it will crash if you repeat a key, you should detect if the passed string is already saved before pushing it, something like:
    `if ($scope.values.indexOf(chip) < 0) {
      $scope.values.push(chip);
    }`

Comment: Thanks, @Arkiller for this suggestion, I've updated for the same.